# how to programatically check for reader macros

Tags: clojure

I have a vector which can contain arbitrary data. I want to check of any of the element is a reader macro, how do I do that ?

`(is-reader-macro? #<DateTime 2012>) ;=> true`

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a string is `read` you cannot tell by the resulting data what the exact reader construct was that created it. The data item you just read is not a reader macro, it's just data.

In your specific example, what you've got is the printed representation of a jodatime DateTime object, which cannot be read - the `#< ... >` construct is meant to prevent that. The actual object that prints like that is just a jodatime DateTime object, not a reader macro.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. So how do I check if the vector contains an actual object against say containing a simple value such as string or int ?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for instance? http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/instance_q