# Is there a simple way to get reader macro string from defmacro?

Tags: clojure

If I run this code

```
(defmacro foo
  [expr]
  (println "expr:" expr))

(foo '(1 2 3))
```

I will get the following print message

```
expr: (quote (1 2 3))
```

but I  want to get the following message

```
expr: '(1 2 3)
```

I want to handle original reader macro string (before transformed) in defmacro. Maybe, I will access the string by reading a file which the macro is used and parse it, but not so cool. Please let me know if you know a much better way to do the mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to programatically check for reader macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520076/how-to-programatically-check-for-reader-macros)

Comment: Or [clojure code modification preserving reader macros](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32250809/5044950)

Comment: In any case, your macro doesn't get the original string of code, so as you said in your question, you'd probably have to access the source code some other way, which wouldn't be particularly simple.

Answer (score 2):

according to http://www.clojure.org/reference/reader

> The behavior of the reader is driven by a combination of built-in constructs and an extension system called the read table.

and

> The read table is currently not accessible to user programs.

so I'd say no. Which is consistent with what I remember from various clojure books.

---

One thing which seemingly can be preserved are [reader-conditionals](http://www.clojure.org/reference/reader#_reader_conditionals)

```
(read-string
  {:read-cond :preserve}
  "[1 2 #?@(:clj [3 4] :cljs [5 6])]")
  ;; [1 2 #?@(:clj [3 4] :cljs [5 6])]
```

Comment: you are correct, the printer does not produce reader macro forms for quote (or syntax quote), once they are read they are  never again going to be drawn with the reader macro form.